# Indefinite pronouns

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

I'm confused with indefinite pronouns such as **all , Some , None , Any** in which the verb used to agree with it can be singular or plural . 
What is the strategy to identify whether the verb is singular or plural . ?

Example statement :

> **All** this information **allows** the problems to be prioritised and the more serious one attended to first.

Why is the verb used 'allows' ? Confused. Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

Words like **information** fall into a category called uncountable nouns. Some other examples are water, furniture, candy, sugar, and air. These nouns are treated as a singular collection of things with no plural form, which is why you use the singular form of a verb with them. However you must use **all** or **some** to indicate plurality. Confusing right?

If you want to indicate that one of these nouns is explicitly singular then you must use the form **a...of**. For example:

a piece of information

a drop of water

a piece of furniture

a piece of candy

a granule of sugar

a gust of air